# How can I push one Git commit without an earlier one?

Tags: git

I have made a `git commit` but I have not pushed. And I am now working on a new bug fix, which should not touch the same files as the first commit.

Is it possible for me to commit this bug fix AND `git push` only this commit?

Comment: It looks like you have asked over 50 questions but have accepted answers to only a small fraction of those. Please consider using the "accept" function to mark the answer that was the most helpful for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the commits leading up to a particular commit are what defines that new commit.

That is, if you have a master → dev → bugfix as shown in the image below:

[master → dev → bugfix http://img.skitch.com/20091029-tbffrg53q73mdipiwcr3g2ywuh.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091029-tbffrg53q73mdipiwcr3g2ywuh.png)

you can push `dev` alone but not `bugfix` alone, but the definition of `bugfix` includes `dev`, so `dev` has no meaning without `bugfix`

However, if you build this bugfix out as a feature branch, you'd have something that looked more like this:

[feature branch http://img.skitch.com/20091029-t3w5qk3bhj3ftx1d9xnk32ibkb.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091029-t3w5qk3bhj3ftx1d9xnk32ibkb.png)

You could still retroactively do that (create a new branch from `origin/master`, cherry-pick the change, and then `git reset --hard HEAD^` on your development branch to get the bugfix change off of it).

Once that's complete, you can forward-port your dev branch with a simple `git rebase master` and it'll look like this:

[new master http://img.skitch.com/20091029-1ts3enwsmsr29imcu7tyk75ett.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091029-1ts3enwsmsr29imcu7tyk75ett.png)

In practice, starting bug fixes from a branch will make this kind of thing a lot easier in general.

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is move the previous commit to a (temporary) branch, and cherry-pick your new commit to the master. For example:

```
# first commit your current work
git branch temp_branch
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git cherry-pick temp_branch
git push
```

Then, temp_branch will contain both your new commits. You can then later pick your previous one back to master:

```
git cherry-pick temp_branch^
git branch -D temp_branch
```

After doing this, your master branch will contain the same two commits as you started with, but in the opposite order.

Answer (score 0):

just do another clone and push your bug fix from there.

Answer (score 0):

Our shop uses personal branches extensively. Basically the process would go like this:

Given that you are currently on the master branch

```
git checkout -b bug_fix_name_that_I_dont_want_to_commit
```

The above creates a branch and checks it out...this is where you put the commits that you are not ready to push.

Now you should be able to make commits to the current branch without affecting the master branch.

When you're ready to publish/push that one commit, just do:

```
git push origin master
```

and your other commits will not go to the origin repository.

When you're ready to incorporate the "bug fix" into the master branch, checkout the master branch and do;

```
git merge bug_fix_name_that_I_dont_want_to_commit
```

I think this answers the question, but if not, just let me know!